# Can you run an old app on a new version of the android

Tags: android, versions

Okay so this doesn't really have much to do with code help but I am just starting my final year project and will be developing preferably for Android mobile devices. The plan is to create it in Android 2.1 as I only have a used HTC hero but my testers have a mix of version androids. and not many have a new HTC One or new Nexus, so i presume that they are all using older versions of the OS.

So what I need to know is, will I be able to create the application in 2.1 and it run on new versions of the OS (preferably phones not tablets, if it matters)?

Comment: A few things you should account for, the HTC Hero uses a 320x480 screen so some of your layouts might not look right on the larger screens (typically 480x800, 960x540, or 1280x720) of new phones.  Also, newer phones use different default themes so make sure you set a specific theme for your app so that your testers see the same style of widgets that you see on your Hero.  So while yes, your app will run on newer versions, your app might look very different from what you're seeing on your Hero if you don't account for the differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can! No issues with that, as far I know.

When you are building your application, in the Manifest file you declare the **`MinSDKVersion`** which specifies the minimum Android OS version needed to run your application. Your application will run on all devices which are above or exactly the minimum SDK version specified.

There is no limit on the maximum version which can run your application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is very easy to run your older android application to the higher android version.
You must specify the **`MinSDKVersion`** must be lower than your emulator or the android device, For more detail please go through the following link. http://grabcodes.blogspot.com

Answer (score 1):

You might want to set also targetSdkVersion=7 and make sure you have the appropriate 2.1 (API 7) in your environment. If you set another value indictating that you will develop for more modern versions and 7 is only the MIN value, you may get annoying and maybe confusing indications that some calls to android api are deprecated in Eclipse. Maybe not a big problem, but could end up wasting your time if you get confused.