# moving a Gingerbread app to KitKat - how

Tags: android

the app was written using Gingerbread. But now i need to convert this app to KitKat. I have no idea how to do this...

I tried to look up some documentation - do I simply install kitkat in eclipse, then import this project, and save and run it ?

Comment: Gingerbread apps will run just fine in KitKat, except that the UI will be horrible...

Comment: OK, then what should a person do to fix this problem of UI looking horrible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a new android OS is released then it is developed in a way so that if the existing applications(the old one) are installed on the new release then they will run without any issues,(with the old interface) as these OS's are perfectly made backward compatible with the applications which was  running on Older version of the OS's.So there are no issues regarding running your application on kitkat.[SEE THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517009/can-you-run-an-old-app-on-a-new-version-of-the-android)

---

**Note:** However vice versa is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Note that KitKat is not the latest version of android, currently, Android Lollipop is the latest.

1. Install the latest SDK from the SDK manager. Start Eclipse, and click on the SDK manager button. You will see a new window that looks like the following:

[image: SDK manager screen]

Make sure you install the latest Android SDK Build-tools and the SDK Platform.

2. Android is made to be backwards-compatible; it will run an existing app developed for lower versions without any issue.
3. Import the new library for your app (`Appcompat` Library v-21). Refer to their [developer website](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html). Then, in your `Manifest`, change the `<target-sdk>` to the latest version of Android (recommended).
4. However, new OSes come with a new UI – this means that it is highly recommended to redesign your app layout to match the new OS. The design guidelines can be found on their [developer website](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html). This process is fairly straight forward – use your original xml layout keeping the `id`s, but change them to match the new design guidelines. More information can be found on their website previously linked.

That's it. Happy porting.